Avocado plant problem
My avocado plant has a strange mildew on some of its leaves.  Not sure what it is or how to treat it.  Anyone know what the problem is?

That is an insect pest.  It could be aphids which can be seen with the eye and come in various colors. When they molt the husks are white which might be what we are seeing.
From the silvery scarring I wonder if this might be thrips.  They are very hard to control as the young live inside the leaves which produces the silvery mottling.  Adults have wings and will spread to other plants.  They will feed on a wide range of plants. Pothos and philodendrons are a favorite but I have also seem them on ponytail palms.
I suggest you look closer and take a closeup with your phone.  If they are thrip the only control that has ever worked for me is put the plant outside in the spring for a few months.  If that is not possible then remove all the leaves and isolate the plant. Check regularly for adult thrip which are the size of a ! and black. They will move around if you poke them with a toothpick or a pin.
